# A problem in extension fields

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory, extension-field, irreducible-polynomials

Let $E$ be an extension field of a field $F$. (That is, let $F$ be a subfield of the field $E$.) Let $\alpha$, $\beta$ $\in $ $E$ such that $\alpha$ is transcendental over $F$ but algebraic over the simple extension $F(\beta)$ of $F$. Is $\beta$ algebraic or transcendental over $F$? I know that $\beta$ is algebraic over $F(\alpha)$.

Here $F(\beta)$ is effectively the field of rational functions in $\beta$ with co-efficients in $F$.

Answer (score 3):

An algebraic extension of an algebraic extension amounts to an algebraic extension.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm afraid I just coouldn't appreciate what your remark says and how it is relevant to my question.

Comment: @SaaqibMahmuud You said $F(\alpha,\beta)$ is transcendental over $F$ but algebraic over $F(\beta)$ and then asked if $F(\beta)$ is algebraic or transcendental over $F$. *If* $F(\beta)$ were algebraic over $F$, then since $F(\alpha,\beta)$ is algebraic over $F(\beta)$ this means that $F(\alpha,\beta)$ is algebraic over $F$, a contradiction. Hence $F(\beta)$ cannot be algebraic over $F$. You should already be familiar with http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_extension. (A simple extension is algebraic iff it's finite degree and transcendental iff it's infinite degree.)

Answer (score 2):

Hint: $[F(\alpha,\beta):F]=[F(\alpha,\beta):F(\beta)][F(\beta):F]$.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on this symbolism?

Comment: @SaaqibMahmuud If $\alpha$ is transcendental then what is $[F(\alpha,\beta):F]$? If $\alpha$ is algebraic over $F(\beta)$ then what is $[F(\alpha,\beta):F(\beta)]$? What does that mean for $[F(\beta):F]$? You should already be familiar with http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degree_of_a_field_extension.